# Lvalue required error TurboC

Tags: c

```
char activity[30];
int choice;

scanf("%d", &choice);
if(choice==1){
    activity = "Sedentary";
}
else if(choice==2){
    activity = "Light Activity";
}
else if(choice==3){
    activity = "Moderate Activity";
}
else if(choice==4){
    activity = "Very Active";
}
else if(choice==5){
    activity = "Extra Active";
}
```

When I compiled, it shows lvalue required error. I don't know what it means, can someone help me.
Sorry about my English.

Edited - title TurboC (typo)

Comment: C# or C? C# doesn't have `scanf`

Comment: Also in C#, it's `string activity` and not `char activity[30]`

Comment: Is there even a Turbo C# product? Do you mean Turbo C or Turbo C++? If it is either of those, the compilers are going to be very out of date, and you should find a newer compiler to work with to learn the language.

Comment: It's really going to help you if you know what language you are coding in. I suggest that you step back and get a better grip on what you are doing.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel i'm sorry about the title typo ._.

Comment: @CloudyMarble i'm sorry about the title typo, allready edit the title ._.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon i'm sorry about the title typo ._.

Comment: @crashmstr i'm sorry about the title typo ._. but my classes still using this compilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you must use `strcpy()` to copy a string.

```
#include<string.h>

...

if(choice==1){
    strcpy(activity, "Sedentary");
}
else if(choice==2){
    strcpy(activity, "Light Activity");
}
else if(choice==3){
    strcpy(activity, "Moderate Activity");
}
else if(choice==4){
    strcpy(activity, "Very Active");
}
else if(choice==5){
    strcpy(activity, "Extra Active");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how can I display the value of activity?

Comment: `puts(activity)` or `printf("Activity = %s", activity)`

Answer (score 0):

Here `activity = "Sedentary";` is the starting address of the array and if you are doing above code the you are something like `0x123344 = "Sedentary"`
So use here strcpy()

```
strcpy(activity, "Sedentary");
```

then it should not show the Lvalue error.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how can I display the value of activity?

Comment: Use printf("%s",activity);